# WKWebView delegate method changes

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, swift4, xcode9

I am working on migrating UIWebView to WKWebView. I have changed all the Delegate methods. I need WKWebView delegate methods equal to below UIWebView delegate method.

I have written below method in UIWebView. Help me to change below code into WKWebView

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    guard let url = request.url else {
       return true
    }

    guard !url.absoluteString.contains("data:application/pdf") else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.action,
                                                            target: self,
                                                            action: #selector(share(sender:)))
        return true
    }

    guard url.pathExtension != "pdf" else {
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        safariVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    guard url.isLogin() == false else {
        AppDelegate.navigationController.signOut(.sessionOnly)
        return false
    }

    guard let mobileSite = url.asMobileSite() else {
        return true
    }

    let mobileRedirect = URLRequest(url: mobileSite)
    webView.loadRequest(mobileRedirect)
    return false

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509990/migrating-from-uiwebview-to-wkwebview)