# WKWebView vs UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios10, ios11, wkwebview

I've an app/project with deployment target version - iOS 10.

I had used `UIWebView`, which is deprecated now and replaced by `WKWebView`. So, I want to replace UIWebView with WKWebView in my project also.

It force me to either use `UIWebView` (with iOS 10) or change deployment target to iOS 11.

I cannot change deployment target but as a middleware solution, I added code (programatically) support for both. I mean, if user's device OS is iOS 11 (or above) then use `WKWebView` else use `UIWebView` (for iOS 10 or below).

**Issue statement:** Storyboard's view controller does not support both versions, I mean, in storyboard, if I set View controller's deployment target to iOS 11 then app crashes in iOS 10 (and obvious it should) and if I set view controller's deployment target to iOS 10, then storyboard does not allow me to build project.

For iOS 10, `WKWebView` shows me this error: [Xcode 9 GM - WKWebView NSCoding support was broken in previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions)

**Question:** How can I make storyboard (View controller) to use `WKWebView` for iOS 11 and `UIWebView` for iOS 10? Is there any configuration setup or option in story board (view controller) that can allow me to add both interface outlets?

Comment: Is there anything specific you are trying to do with it in IB / Storyboard? If not, I would simply use a "placeholder" UIView, and replace it in `viewDidLoad` with a `WKWebView`.

Comment: @DonMag Can I do it with UIViewWebview (UIWebView to WKWebView)? How? Have ever tried it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* simply create and add a `WKWebView` via code.

If you want a visual representation for layout purposes in your Storyboard, here is one way to do it.

Add a standard `UIView` in your view controller in your Storyboard. This will act as a "holder" for your web view. Connect it to an `IBOutlet`, then in `viewDidLoad` add an instance of `WKWebView` as a subview of that "holder" view.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    // standard UIView, added in Storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewHolder: UIView!

    // instance of WKWebView
    let wkWebView: WKWebView = {
        let v = WKWebView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the WKWebView to the "holder" UIView
        webViewHolder.addSubview(wkWebView)

        // pin to all 4 edges
        wkWebView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewHolder.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        wkWebView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewHolder.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        wkWebView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewHolder.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        wkWebView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewHolder.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // load a URL into the WKWebView
        if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") {
            wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }

        // from here on out, use wkWebView just as if you had added it in your storyboard

    }

}
```

Comment: ^This is your answer.  Instead of having to change deployment targets, or using the `if #available(iOS, 10*){ }` etc etc...This will actually give your webView a performance boost, especially if you are using a lot of javascript.    Don't forgot your `import WebKit` at the top of your ViewController file.  I have used WKWebView in projects built for iOS >= 9