# Getting UIWebView Error When Trying To Upload Flutter app To ItunesConnect

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app to the app store but, I keep getting the error that my app has this issue:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Here are my dependances:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^3.2.0
```

Environment:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter_facebook_login: 
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_annotation: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: 
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^0.1.8
  image_picker: 0.6.0+1
  image_cropper: ^1.0.1
  path: any
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  clippy_flutter: ^1.1.0
  gradient_widgets: ^0.4.1
  gradient_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.0.0+4
  google_sign_in: 
  firebase_auth:
  rxdart: 
  font_awesome_flutter:
  bubble_bottom_bar: ^1.2.0
  flutter_rating: ^0.0.2
  sticky_headers: ^0.1.7
  google_maps_flutter:
  geolocator: ^5.1.1+1
  flutter_google_places: 
  google_maps_webservice:
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  source_gen:
  flutter_counter: ^1.0.3
  share:
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  dropdown_menu:
  flutter_flip_view:
  permission_handler: ^3.0.1
  giffy_dialog:
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4
  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.5
  catcher: ^0.3.4
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^1.3.0
```

My pods:

```
PODS:
  - AppAuth (1.3.0):
    - AppAuth/Core (= 1.3.0)
    - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (= 1.3.0)
  - AppAuth/Core (1.3.0)
  - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (1.3.0)
  - Bolts (1.9.1):
    - Bolts/AppLinks (= 1.9.1)
    - Bolts/Tasks (= 1.9.1)
  - Bolts/AppLinks (1.9.1):
    - Bolts/Tasks
  - Bolts/Tasks (1.9.1)
  - catcher (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - device_info (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - FBSDKCoreKit (4.39.1):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (4.39.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
  - Firebase/Auth (6.24.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.5.3)
  - Firebase/Core (6.24.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.5.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.24.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.7.0)
  - firebase_auth (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Auth (~> 6.0)
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core_web (0.1.0):
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.5.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.7)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.5.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (6.5.3):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (1.1.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.7.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.3)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.3.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 3.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
  - FirebaseInstallations (1.2.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.6)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - flutter_facebook_login (0.0.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (= 4.39.1)
    - FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1)
    - Flutter
  - flutter_mailer (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - fluttertoast (0.0.2):
    - Flutter
  - geocoder (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - geolocator (5.1.3):
    - Flutter
  - google_api_availability (2.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - google_maps_flutter (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - GoogleMaps
  - google_sign_in (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0)
  - google_sign_in_web (0.8.1):
    - Flutter
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.5.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (6.1.0)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (3.1.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 6.1)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleMaps (2.7.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 2.7.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (2.7.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (2.7.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GoogleSignIn (5.0.2):
    - AppAuth (~> 1.2)
    - GTMAppAuth (~> 1.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.6.0):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.6.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMAppAuth (1.0.0):
    - AppAuth/Core (~> 1.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher (~> 1.1)
  - GTMSessionFetcher (1.4.0):
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Full (= 1.4.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.4.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Full (1.4.0):
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (= 1.4.0)
  - image_cropper (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - TOCropViewController (~> 2.4.0)
  - image_picker (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - location_permissions (2.0.2):
    - Flutter
  - nanopb (1.30905.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 1.30905.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/decode (1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/encode (1.30905.0)
  - package_info (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - permission_handler (3.3.0):
    - Flutter
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.8)
  - share (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - shared_preferences (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - TOCropViewController (2.4.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - catcher (from `.symlinks/plugins/catcher/ios`)
  - device_info (from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`)
  - firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - firebase_core_web (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)
  - flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)
  - flutter_mailer (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_mailer/ios`)
  - flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/ios`)
  - fluttertoast (from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`)
  - geocoder (from `.symlinks/plugins/geocoder/ios`)
  - geolocator (from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios`)
  - google_api_availability (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_api_availability/ios`)
  - google_maps_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`)
  - google_sign_in (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`)
  - google_sign_in_web (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_web/ios`)
  - image_cropper (from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios`)
  - image_picker (from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`)
  - location_permissions (from `.symlinks/plugins/location_permissions/ios`)
  - package_info (from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios`)
  - permission_handler (from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios`)
  - share (from `.symlinks/plugins/share/ios`)
  - shared_preferences (from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - AppAuth
    - Bolts
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseAuthInterop
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
    - GoogleMaps
    - GoogleSignIn
    - GoogleUtilities
    - GTMAppAuth
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC
    - TOCropViewController

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  catcher:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/catcher/ios"
  device_info:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios"
  firebase_auth:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios"
  firebase_core:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios"
  firebase_core_web:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios"
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter
  flutter_facebook_login:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios"
  flutter_mailer:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_mailer/ios"
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/ios"
  fluttertoast:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios"
  geocoder:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/geocoder/ios"
  geolocator:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios"
  google_api_availability:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/google_api_availability/ios"
  google_maps_flutter:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios"
  google_sign_in:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios"
  google_sign_in_web:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_web/ios"
  image_cropper:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios"
  image_picker:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios"
  location_permissions:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/location_permissions/ios"
  package_info:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios"
  permission_handler:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios"
  share:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/share/ios"
  shared_preferences:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  AppAuth: 73574f3013a1e65b9601a3ddc8b3158cce68c09d
  Bolts: 8c1e8aab2f603387b8b9924f57d1d64f43d3ffdc
  catcher: e5585ed31458c849f4fd9c3719b2fcb0188b8918
  device_info: cbf09d2ec12aa7110e0b09fabe54b5bd6c8efe74
  FBSDKCoreKit: f442aa96179cc9b382bb4abeb7e340a47cca8f91
  FBSDKLoginKit: c3079d9a4db27c492287b1eed7a4272b28cf8a59
  Firebase: b28e55c60efd98963cd9011fe2fac5a10c2ba124
  firebase_auth: d99b993c1405096e66c58211b1cd956c23eed1c5
  firebase_core: 87e4c7cef68de46c0326ce2ee907fc7e365ead7e
  firebase_core_web: d501d8b946b60c8af265428ce483b0fff5ad52d1
  FirebaseAnalytics: 7386fc2176e3f93ad8ef34b5b1f2b33a891e4962
  FirebaseAuth: 7047aec89c0b17ecd924a550c853f0c27ac6015e
  FirebaseAuthInterop: a0f37ae05833af156e72028f648d313f7e7592e9
  FirebaseCore: e610482f64097b0e9f056cd97bc6b33dfabcbb6a
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 4a773a47bd83bbd5a9b1ccf1ce7caa8b2d535e67
  FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop: 296e2c5f5314500a850ad0b83e9e7c10b011a850
  FirebaseInstallations: 2119fb3e46b0a88bfdbf12562f855ee3252462fa
  Flutter: 0e3d915762c693b495b44d77113d4970485de6ec
  flutter_facebook_login: be61e24a4b7d621515353c6b4583d1981bdaa3d6
  flutter_mailer: 2ef5a67087bc8c6c4cefd04a178bf1ae2c94cd83
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: dc0b544e129eebb77a6bfb1239d4d1c673a60a35
  fluttertoast: b644586ef3b16f67fae9a1f8754cef6b2d6b634b
  geocoder: 3cfab70531a0b367e917bafe82df4c30f6d4c45a
  geolocator: 2d5da6891d865c0f1b4f851683eed890dd9c8bc1
  google_api_availability: 163b30f802e6148c67f092aa4501c90ddd8eec8d
  google_maps_flutter: df4e7de95264aa0a2f11aac0fc7e313acb8ffc7e
  google_sign_in: 6bd214b9c154f881422f5fe27b66aaa7bbd580cc
  google_sign_in_web: 52deb24929ac0992baff65c57956031c44ed44c3
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 4c644d86835d827bab30ab6aabb9ecaf1f500735
  GoogleDataTransport: f6f8eba931df03ebd2232ff4645aa85f8f47b5ab
  GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport: d70a561f7d236af529fee598835caad5e25f6d3d
  GoogleMaps: f79af95cb24d869457b1f961c93d3ce8b2f3b848
  GoogleSignIn: 7137d297ddc022a7e0aa4619c86d72c909fa7213
  GoogleUtilities: 39530bc0ad980530298e9c4af8549e991fd033b1
  GTMAppAuth: 4deac854479704f348309e7b66189e604cf5e01e
  GTMSessionFetcher: 6f5c8abbab8a9bce4bb3f057e317728ec6182b10
  image_cropper: 88160bea3665a5fab6989ff3a6825811b8f19a3d
  image_picker: 16e5fec1fbc87fd3b297c53e4048521eaf17cd06
  location_permissions: 67cfaff583afbb027a9f9248196f4b79c40f3cdc
  nanopb: c43f40fadfe79e8b8db116583945847910cbabc9
  package_info: 48b108e75b8802c2d5e126f208ef540561c98aef
  permission_handler: 67637977b227d62d46bfbf524f335f8568de5a73
  PromisesObjC: c119f3cd559f50b7ae681fa59dc1acd19173b7e6
  share: 0b2c3e82132f5888bccca3351c504d0003b3b410
  shared_preferences: 1feebfa37bb57264736e16865e7ffae7fc99b523
  TOCropViewController: 368d8df3ea43b62c3dc5a61f11b9048274d240bd

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 3dbe063e9c90a5d7c9e4e76e70a821b9e2c1d271

COCOAPODS: 1.9.1
```

I have done flutter clean, flutter build ios, flutter upgrade, deleted the podfile.lock and re-installed it but still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific issue related to the flutter.

This is a warning by the Apple support team. That says the UIWebView is not acceptable which is now being deprecated. So, you have to replace it with WKWebView.

From April 2020, UIWebView is not acceptable in any iOS application so you have to replace this with WKWebView.
Maybe the deadline extended to June 2020.
But UIWebView is deprecated for new builds to upload apps to the App Store.

For this, you could follow this link:-

https://medium.com/@kiransjadhav111/how-to-use-wkwebview-migrating-uiwebview-to-wkwebview-with-swift-30506885d916

or

[Migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509990/migrating-from-uiwebview-to-wkwebview)